# Styled Components, required props defined as defaultProps show as missing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, styled-components, definitelytyped

Required props that are defined as `defaultProps` show as missing when using the component.

```
// Button.ts
interface ButtonProps {
  size: 'small' | 'medium' | 'large';
  inverted: boolean;
  raised: boolean;
}

const Button = styled('button')<ButtonProps>`...`

Button.defaultProps = {
  size: 'medium',
  inverted: false,
  raised: false,
}

export default Button
```

```
// Hello.tsx
import Button from './Button'

const Hello = () => <Button>Hello</Button>
```

Button is highlighted in red and displays this error message:

```
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 
'Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>,
HTMLButtonElement>, "form" | "style" | "title" | "key" | "autoFocus" |
"disabled" | "formAction" | ... 255 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> &
{ ...; } & ButtonProps, "form" | ... 329 more ... | "raised"> & 
Partial<...>, "form" | ... 329 ...': size, inverted, and 1 more.
```

Versions:

```
"@types/styled-components": "^4.1.9",
"@types/react": "^16.8.5",
"@types/react-dom": "^16.8.2",

"typescript": "^3.3.3333",
"styled-components": "^4.1.3"
"react": "^16.8.3",
"react-dom": "^16.8.3",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that assigning `defaultProps` will not change it's type which will remain the default of `Partial<StyledComponentProps<"button", any, ButtonProps, never>>`. You can explicitly type the `const` but typing a lot of types is never fun. A simpler approach is to use another HOC (everything can be solved with another HOC )  that mutates the type of `defaultProps` to contain the default props you actually set on the component:

```
// Button.ts
interface ButtonProps {
    size: 'small' | 'medium' | 'large';
    inverted: boolean;
    raised: boolean;
}

function withDefault<T extends { defaultProps?: Partial<TDefaults> }, TDefaults>(o: T, defaultProps: TDefaults): T & { defaultProps: TDefaults } {
    o.defaultProps = defaultProps;
    return o as any;
}

const Button = withDefault(styled('button') <ButtonProps>`...`, {
    size: 'medium',
    inverted: false,
    raised: false,
})

export default Button

const Hello = () => <Button>Hello</Button> // OK now
```

Comment: Do you think this behavior is intended or is this a workaround? This definitely works, It's just defaultProps have worked in the past. So I'm not sure if recent typescript versions don't allow for default props anymore (and this is the new way of doing it) or if there is something wrong with the styled-components types.

Comment: @MattThomas It very much depends on where you used default props. They should work in class components, they should also work with functions if you assign it after declaring the function (TS will add it to the function type in such cases). But if you assign a `const` you either set it's type with a `defaultProps` in it or you have it inferred in some other way ..

Comment: you might be interested in the workaround @types/styled-component's maintainer suggested, which is similar to yours; checkout my edited answer for source

Comment: It behavior still not same as when didn't use styled-component. all props changes to optional type while i need some props is required.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit** While I'm personally ok with this behavior, it's not consistent with behavior from a normal React component ([typescript supports `defaultProps`](http://ComponentWithoutDefault)).

I look around a bit, and it seems that this was fixed in [`@types/styled-components`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/31903), but then [removed due to it introducing another bug](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/32200).

Note from the type maintainer:

> However, TS doesn't set type of newly set defaultProps (aka expando), so don't expect it would allow to skip required props.
>   In order to modify the type, in the tests I added a simple helper function that sets defaultProps and returns modified type. This is meant to be an example only.

Here's that [example:](https://github.com/Igorbek/DefinitelyTyped/blob/024685f00eafeb9ad8a8c19b0cf33d57c5b75fa0/types/styled-components/test/index.tsx#L986)

```
// example of a simple helper that sets defaultProps and update the type
type WithDefaultProps<C, D> = C & { defaultProps: D };

function withDefaultProps<C, D>(component: C, defaultProps: D): WithDefaultProps<C, D> {
    (component as WithDefaultProps<C, D>).defaultProps = defaultProps;
    return component as WithDefaultProps<C, D>;
}
```

This helper does fix the problem (and is similar to [@TitianCernicova-Dragomir's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54961367/10340970) so you should consider marking his answer as correct if you accept this as a correct workaround).

```
/* setup */
interface Props {
    requiredProp: number;
}

const defaultProps: Props = {
    requiredProp: 1,
};

const Component = styled.div<Props>``;
const ComponentWithDefault = withDefaultProps(Component, defaultProps);

export { Component, ComponentWithDefault };

/* usage */
import { Component, ComponentWithDefault } from './component.tsx';

const a = <Component /> // Property requiredProp is missing...
const b = <ComponentWithDefault /> // no error
```

Requirements:

```
"@types/styled-components": "^4.1.12",
"typescript": "^3.2.4",
```

`defaultProps` with styled-components did worked in the past — if you're interested in keeping that behavior, I think reverting to older version of @types/styled-components might help; I think it's 4.1.8 but I'm not sure.

**Original answer**

---

Perhaps not the answer you're looking for, but I find this behavior desireable. 
If you have already defined certain properties in `defaultProps`, wouldn't that make those properties optional?

I'd make defaulted props optional:

```
interface ButtonProps {
  size?: 'small' | 'medium' | 'large';
  inverted?: boolean;
  raised?: boolean;
}
```

Or keep it intact, but wrap in `Partial<>` since you're already provide default for all of them

```
const Button = styled('button')<Partial<ButtonProps>>`...`
```

---

Another things I usually do is to define `defaultProps` first in a variable, so I can properly define their interface:

```
interface Props { ... }

const defaultProps: Props = { ... }

const Component = styled.div<Props>`...`
Component.defaultProps = defaultProps
```

Comment: This is interesting, the only issue is required props get marked as optional with `Partial`.  Also, I like the idea of `const defaultProps: Props` but styled-components adds html attributes to your type for example `onClick` if it's `styled('button')`. I could extend the `ButtonProps` interface with the HTMLButtonAttribues (dont remember what it's called), it just seems unnecessary.

Comment: @MattThomas I looked around a bit, updated my answer w/ example from @types/styled-components's maintainer

Answer (score 0):

A way more robust way to apply default props is by using functional composition.

```
function withDefaults<T extends React.ComponentType<any>, U extends Partial<React.ComponentProps<T> & JSX.IntrinsicAttributes>>(Component: T, defaults: U): React.FC<Omit<React.ComponentProps<T>, keyof U> & Partial<U>> {
  return props => React.createElement(Component, { ...defaults, ...props });
}

type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
```

Usage:

```
const ButtonWithDefaults = withDefaults(Button, {
  size: 'medium',
  inverted: false,
  raised: false,
});

() => (
<ButtonWithDefaults>
  Hello
</ButtonWithDefaults>
);
```

It achieves everything:

- ✅ nothing is mutated
- ✅ types are checked
- ✅ you get proper code completion
- ✅ no `as any` assertion

Comment: I fear this is reinventing the wheel. React had default properties which is supported by Typescript and by the React typings. I don't think just because we struggle to get the types to workout  is a justification to roll out a custom solution to a solved problem. We should just get the types to workout ..

Comment: In an ideal world, I agree. However, how `defaultProps` are handled right now leaves much to be desired. [LibraryManagedAttributes](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/0337cd94b1ed7bb858f45cd33bf6878f3aee38b9/types/react/index.d.ts#L2775-L2779) were supposed to solve issues like that, but there are clearly limitations to it. Besides, they work only since TypeScript 3.0.

Comment: The OP has a dependency to a version above 3.0. Even with below 3.0 a HOC approach could just assert the component type has fewer required props and still use `defaultProps` behind the scenes. The limitation (al least in this case) comes from the fact that an assignment does not mutate the type of the target object. I believe the solution is to just change the type of `defaultProps` not drop `defaultProps` altogether. But that is just my opinion I guess 

Answer (score 0):

A simpler and better solution would be to assign defaults in render (or where you're using them) while destructuring, I do this often, here's an example:

```
// Button.ts
interface ButtonProps {
    size?: 'small' | 'medium' | 'large'; // making optional via '?' sign
    inverted?: boolean;
    raised?: boolean;
}

render() {
    const { size = 'medium', inverted = false, raised = false } = this.props;

    // Use these props, if none are passed by user, these defaults will be used 
    // otherwise user versions will be used
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a regular component, then pass that component's reference to styled and set the styles just as you would with a tag

```
const PlainButton = props: ButtonProps => (/* your jsx here */);
const Button = styled(PlainButton)`
  color: #A5FFA5;
`;
```